# JQuery append click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a strange problem with JQuery when I try to click on append element that is inside timeout function
I got the following code:

```
function generate(){
    box = shuffle(box);
    console.log(box);
    $("#game").empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        $("#game").append("<div class=box>" + box[i] + "</div>");
    }
}

function lvl1(){
    box = shuffle(box);
    console.log(box);
    $("#game").empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        $("#game").append("<div class=box>" + box[i] + "</div>");
    }
}

generate();

setTimeout(function(){
    lvl1();
}, 1000);

$(".box").click(function(){
    alert("OK");
});
```

If I try to click on box within a 1 sec the alert is showed correctly but if I try to click after the timeout it does nothing also no error is showing

http://jsfiddle.net/f4kgvaL5/

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with all your code and html...easier to help you jsfiddle.net

Comment: Please take the time to format your code correctly. It makes it much easier for you and others to read.

Comment: Why are you expecting clicking on `.box` to do anything other than show an alert?

Comment: Well thats the problem it doesn't show after timeout fire lvl1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.box` elements are being appended dynamically, so you need to use a delegated event:

```
$("#game").on('click', '.box', function () {
    alert("OK");
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/f4kgvaL5/1/)

Comment: I think I won by 6 seconds :P

Comment: Why the first one works but one inside setTImeOut don't?

Comment: I would imagine it's because the first group of `.box` elements are available to the DOM on page load. Subsequent sets are loaded via AJAX.

Comment: Yes this is correct. When you call generate you initialize the first set of box elements then you attach the event to them. However subsequent calls you dont attach the event so the alert is never fired.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an event delegation issue. On the new boxes created during lvl1 you arnt assigning the event handler again.

Try

```
$( "#game" ).on( "click", ".box", function(){
    alert("OK");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

see the code:-

```
 $(document).on("click",".box",function(){
            alert("OK");
 });
```

working example:-
http://jsfiddle.net/f4kgvaL5/2/

thanks